# How change config file for custom folder in opencart Like Admin and catalog

Tags: opencart

I Added a new Seller folder with(Model, Controllers, Language, View) in Opencart 3 like Admin and Catalog But when I changed the config file of the seller folder its working fine in localhost but when run in server the server it says "response xyz.com is currently unable to handle this request".
How i can change the config file so it can be accessible in the live server

Comment: If anyone know how to handle config file for seller kindly help me Thanks

Comment: Hi, just wanted to confirm if you created a new Seller folder or replaced the original with it? In conclusion are you having 3 folders right now: Admin, Catalog, Seller?

Comment: @SternChen Yes now I have 3 Folder Admin, Catalog, and Seller. Admin and Catalog working fine but the Seller not working on the server. In Xampp localhost Seller works.

Comment: It's quite challenging to find the cause with this limited info. What's the error code for this "response xyz.com is currently unable to handle this request" error? If it was **error code 500** most probably was due to terminated from PHP script. So I will recommend if you able access to your server, you can check your server error log for what causing this error. Usually the log file will named as "error_log" and located at the directory of the controller entry. e.g. public_html/admin